# Midori: changing source code to change http handling behaviour

Tags: c, midori

I am working in a project where i need to change a browser source code to change the way it behaves when receiving a certain http response Status-Code. When these kind of packets are received i need to catch them, analize the message body and do something accordingly.

I am struggling to get access to a HTTP message body. Either request or response. I have tried pretty much everything. I can use/alter headers as i wish, i can insert my messages in the queue(calling libsoup/midori primitives).

Midori uses libsoup session signals for handling the messages. "request-started" and "request-queued". I added the avaiable "request-unqueued" which allows me for further granular control in the http life-cycle.

I know there are Soup_Message specific signals but i have not found how to work with them although i feel like i should.

Please feel free to help me, guide me to any links, documentation, anything that can give me an hint.

TL:DR: Need to access Http response body/content and can only read Headers.